# Alternative to group by for cosmos db

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Given that cosmos db does not support group by, what is a good alternative to achieve similar functionality:

```
Select sum(*) , groupterm from tble group by groupterm
```

Can I efficiently achieve this in a cosmos stored procedure?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Group by is now supported in Cosmos db SQL API. You will be needing SDK version 3.3 or higher

> Azure Cosmos DB currently supports GROUP BY in .NET SDK 3.3 or later.
>   Support for other language SDK's and the Azure Portal is not currently
>   available but is planned.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-group-by

Answer (score 11):

As [Cosmos_DB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmos_DB) states as follows:

> Aggregation capability in SQL limited to COUNT, SUM, MIN, MAX, AVG functions. No support for GROUP BY or other aggregation functionality found in database systems. However, stored procedures can be used to implement in-the-database aggregation capability.

> Can I efficiently achieve this in a cosmos stored procedure?

**For .NET and Node.js**

Larry Maccherone has provided a great package [documentdb-lumenize](https://github.com/lmaccherone/documentdb-lumenize) which supports Aggregations (Group-by, Pivot-table, and N-dimensional Cube) and Time Series Transformations as Stored Procedures in DocumentDB.

Additionally, for Python and Scala, you could refer to [azure-cosmosdb-spark](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-spark).

Comment: The Lumenize stored procedure can be called from any client side library. I just only include examples of how to do it from node.js and .NET but Python, Java, etc. could all use it.

Comment: This looks good thanks, I'll give it a go. Looking through the docs, it only shows examples of grouping by a single field, is this correct, or can I add multiple fields to the group term in the config?

Comment: And equally if I want to sum multiple properties of the document, is that possible?

Comment: AFAIK, you could only config `groupBy`, `field` as a single field.

Answer (score 4):

Finally, Azure Cosmos DB currently supports [`GROUP BY in .NET SDK 3.3`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-group-by) or later. Support for other language SDK's and the Azure Portal is not currently available but is planned.

```
<group_by_clause> ::= GROUP BY <scalar_expression_list>

<scalar_expression_list> ::=
          <scalar_expression>
        | <scalar_expression_list>, <scalar_expression>
```

[image]

Comment: but this is not about .NET SDK!