# Property reference is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, document-database

Azure Cosmos Document DB throws an error on executing a query like this -

```
SELECT DISTINCT VALUE 
{ 
    DocumentName: c.Name, 
    Count: COUNT(c.id),
    Target: c.Target
}
FROM c where c.Target != null
```

Error -

> SC2102: Property reference 'c.Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause
>
> SC2102: Property reference 'c.Target' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

In regular SQL I would solve this by adding

```
GROUP BY c.Name, c.Target
```

at the end of the query but Cosmos DB does not seem to support a group clause.

> SC1001: Syntax error, incorrect syntax near 'GROUP'.

I'm wondering if a GROUP-like clause is supported. And if it is not supported, what is the meaning of this error?

Comment: I think you may refer the accepted answer of this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45270125/alternative-to-group-by-for-cosmos-db

Comment: I wanted to do this in the query like the one in question since it is possible to optimize by seeing what uses fewer RUs this way. Doing it in LINQ (or lumenize as well) might not give me that advantage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [azure cosmos db feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/18561901-add-group-by-support-for-aggregate-functions), `group by` is currently in active development and will be shipped ASAP.

For now, you could refer to the SO thread [Grouping by a field in DocumentDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33373198/grouping-by-a-field-in-documentdb) which is very helpful for you. The answer has written a library [documentdb-lumenize](https://github.com/lmaccherone/documentdb-lumenize) based on [Document Db stored procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming) that you can try it.

If you do concern the RUs, of course you could metric RUs consumption of stored procedure.

You could call `executeStoredProcedure` method in Cosmos DB SDK, then use `getRequestCharge()` method. It won't show in the portal.

Such as Java code:

```
StoredProcedureResponse resourceResponse = documentClient.executeStoredProcedure("dbs/db/colls/item/sprocs/b",requestOptions ,null);
System.out.println(resourceResponse.getRequestCharge());
```

Comment: So do you think that the current message is misleading?

Comment: @NikhilGirraj Yes, I think it's misleading. Maybe you could submit feedback to azure team.

Comment: With this comment, this answer seems what I needed. Thanks.