# How can I perform a "Group By" query directly or indirectly on Cosmos DB?

Tags: r, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps, azure-blob-storage

I have a Cosmos DB collection with 4 millions items.
My main problem is how I can perform a 'group by' query on it.

For now I export it to json.gz blob storage. Convert it to a local CSV file from a local C# program. Then run a simple R script on it that performs that group by.

I would like to run the whole process in Azure (using a Azure Logic App).

What would be the best way to do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For .NET and Node.js

Larry Maccherone has provided a great package documentdb-lumenize which supports Aggregations (Group-by, Pivot-table, and N-dimensional Cube) and Time Series Transformations as Stored Procedures in DocumentDB.
Additionally, for Python and Scala, you could refer to azure-cosmosdb-spark.

You can refer this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45270125/alternative-to-group-by-for-cosmos-db).

Hope it helps.